# How do I remove or change screen lock settings in macOS?

Tags: macos, mojave, screen-lock

Since upgrading to Mojave my Mac screen locks within seconds. I tried to change the 'privacy' settings (yes I clicked on the padlock) but it still won't let me change anything.

**How else may I try resolving this?**

I am not a tech head so would appreciate any answers in layman's terms.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) You can start by checking the settings under System Preferences app → Energy Saver and System Preferences app → Security & Privacy → General.

Comment: Do you have the admin account? You can check by going to System Preferences -> Users and Groups, under current user it will show your account, and whether it is type admin or standard. 
What happens when you click on the padlock? What happens if you try to change the time in The first is the System Preferences -> security & privacy -> general -> Require password?

Answer (score 25):

If you have the admin account you should be able to change the required settings.

The lock screen is affected by 3 settings.

The first is the **System Preferences -> security & privacy -> general -> Require password** 'some time' after sleep or screen saver begins.
When you try to change this you should get a prompt for a password. If this does not work you may not have the admin account.
This setting dictates how long after the computer sleeps till it locks.

The second setting setting is how long it takes to sleep in the first place.

**System Preferences -> energy saver -> battery and power adaptor -> turn display off** after 'some time'
This would make the computer wait longer to turn off the screen.

**System Preferences -> desktop and screen saver -> start after** 'some time'.
This is the screen saver setting as the screen locks after the screen saver or display sleeping.

If you don't have the admin account and aren't allowed to change these settings then you have to talk to whoever has the admin account.